# Using Altair's interval selection as a filter in a multi-view chart

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite, vega

In my concatenated chart, I’m using an interval selection as a filter (see the GIF, Python code, and VL spec below).

Even though my selection appears to be empty, my filtered chart still shows some data. What I'd like to achieve is to show the average temperature, for each station, based on the date range selected in the interval selection.

Is anyone able to have a look and nudge me in the right direction?

Here's [a reproducible example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-HU7XSqmAEIgrN-poVvVPJet9Yd9396cjanzOmdBwqtmep5hkhaItwzRrIYBREpg5bcDWIB1jOTYtm2r4dpQjBwDAvb9oOa4npOR6pheaqLsuYqrshG6oduGFYThH6HgRY5Eeec6YNe3C3qUD6YE+L6dph2G4QOPS9IuMAuPeILuHAgIZIYnqiqQmgduimKJAAvDpiQAOQAMIAKIAHLJAASgAggAMokAAKlnmT2en+ry3CrAwzDILc9wkiA2j6IYzS6MWNgQHYVxuJAziuI4SgIAgOQICu-nxHs3DCnClobDBbg7Eo5SVMgEg1PkYD1JiQVtB0lzdE8gacnSYZGoKcUJUlKWYgkQSZU0FqBL8HwaraSSpAEjqENkmBen6AbUsGXKTNMxpuEo-JwOWjjLs0njWRKsrIAAnGweS9WiGJYpQLiqCAAC0gqDdahgAMqhnAyYwoG+KaISxISQklBSYq+yggpsWgN+CZJnsTSQ7+mbiXyHlMCgPknXyopKG4GkvJjt0sM0MCHVUMAnM0yhVBIAAcbBKD5BN0FTSgHM0dAHGAADspNZr0Q02ml9rjZkk3OtqmHNBAuh0IkQOJCZACaQQACR1H4WNNGIhD+JQyAAPS61MyUdggHyMKQzQdu9uuq9oBuYMlt2mB8mAGywHYHBzHZsB2ABWV3pdsKhKKmhCbaAeME0TJNkxT1O0-TrNMyzbOc9zIOB5RIDumwt1sFTt0HFTyQcMgJccEEOMvfLVkGZKz1GYkgiWSZBkAPIGT2iQAJJmUZ5kmZZyRd63A+UhSyAAGy3B2tzuZByBVDPfmqoY2e5-nhfF2wpfb+X3CV00xlmVZtkOU5Y+WpPVMdhIc8sigi8c8vKVr3nBdF2Xu9sBXF2GAAQpKb03obKtzll3SyABxRyllu6937oPYeA9rIX2BBPN2E877hDdhIZ+mdX4bw-l-HeP9KpNBsn-Zu8tYHJD7gPIeI8bKJEsl3cydlW7mWSCglAE8JAdkOpg1gfDcEvHwQXDmW8d7EP3r-Jo5l26CCMs9Gh5kuGT0OjPARk8hGcHDi-NgJx15iIkZ-EhLxnrV0srXeujdm5tw7tQ2hCCGGqI5o-TRE9tG6LwfonOb8PbGK-qY-+gDgHWVASZcBUCrIOPgfQpBLiDg300dPFgwjV4+MMf4z+UjzqkJAOQyhMS6GIMYcw1h7DOG-HHmgjsHNNE4J0RnERGS-HiOyXvXJLwj4WUYWfHsCT3b1PdmkpooiDgTwCTkg+IA5EGQUUovuLjF6zxAMycI08n6NJXqMlpG8JntO-tIvJ5ia51wbk3Fu7dO492UcU5xVTL4c14SstZqMOwTxGVnXZBd9lEI6dM7pJ97KOX6Q84ETyOylVed5SFnyxm-Mkf8mR+TrIUIVkUpxSCmEsLYRw1RU9alDKpnC754zJlIryQAoBICwGQOgRiuJNl8XqNvqs+entbgkoMX4245LDmdMMLM+ZyiXFuyppog43sqhct8RvXlByglNBOZYs5NjLn2JuY4xlLjvb8LZffGFDSvHNO5XKvliqQBUtCeEyJ9LNWxJKcgsFKAObe1ZdC6eRqmnpNNQXeVfz+UAtMj00+IKXEeKhfPXhh0ZWZP9YiwNyKCnovtXcrFZTcWVP1Kg6+4r9XhE9l67ZXzfUHBYOao5LwhWKJFc65AHMNnJKXlsvRpby0KsrVXU51iLl2OuXAtNlkXGeqGdKlt3i20VoFU0K1NKIl0uiamzFTK60c0LZo6+nLx0mtlQXdtAaLWAt6WG1d18jj5sEUW1tu6y1TumcmqhS7GW2QzRUgZGCL3FXebGvxEg73IuVVY85tirkMpKS43h7r56LwOD+jef6O3TpAEe0N59V0eJYBK7926fU3oQweztM6QlzttYugdy6nXZpdXUz9KS4MF3wwmi1D6wMMJfTit9q7vYfuhYkrdxrcOZKqP+vJ1aFkqNXc8zRnsPk4Z2aW4TiHpmAdVb20DT7wOSY7Hm3j2n6MHEUwRpDLGNNsexeUvFq63G0b03JktN7DNMcI5a4jYTaVRJgaZ+Jq63YvPntPfj3r5MOZE104NQK+kuPUZhz9vDNkCeC5kg4oXBXyJrYsutNNCWftzfp5LSmAMWKA2qvtrHR6rvUTx+eHjiV2bGfloz0zZ1ufnR5srK6qP1uvnq3jfG8spcPuF49aHOtU0SVVg1V6J03oa054zqLCledKRxyznWOZivcc2hL9nMlsAGzMtL4movZehZ7Md22xl7YK8corqmQMavI9q1dAXNGL1qxd0lV3GvIuazahdnnHuOtFdpzb72gs7b8V9ubQbj7DdBWt7rRL9NQ5Mc5kzgOzOvtW-1F1iSYu6ZjXV75bBDr7bE7WtbvCJvhGvvF8HoiSf7ZUz2+7-bbnLoGX5g13s6fFoZ6T67LxfvubtRj7za3Yweq2-T4nAvvt5PR+z595nM3Mo0Z+xJvPr2GMZ4LwwKHgUjZx-W3hkaDWwaJ76vOZPDsU+N64k7-nYWW93dbvXSrbss-VWzrVmnOsT3UT16DzuPtW8IdDn7rm-ttaW5R+33t8fQfo27+XLxFe+8xytrNxuJ7ro1yHmXYf9sG8i1xjsieDVveT201PqW5npYk-79ROmnda+mzrmvEebvduA979r+Lr5m-CIvQnofXed9R0hkvJ7KeDNiwXvnxOJ+BOc8L1rouldA9XYkof3CF-a7fmwZfUyk0LZTWL5bFns-VLdrvhe0vF9W4RZP6Z5OMv+45Zt87hfXfP5X0h5nXvUrJbfFaec9aFSDZPP-E-SlKPEXMjTfNjfFW-IZWTMfHXaAilNPM-R9C-djK-fFHnTRbjKA4vIbVDeHe3GrCVZPeNF-ZFN-RvHPIPA1QPWgpnT3IA9TC-AZFvVg9g93FzalFrUjAHRA8XHPRHDXE6F3HXOg--GHENQ3Sg8eDmKQ6FN2VJWQw-eQmA7AtFXA8Qy-VXOtAPdXaFM9ZPfdLvKtW3d-e3PjTRXzKwjgnvErbgow3gzbLQ9Aw-aw+gvJafI3VQ7BJtC3Xw-ONgfwhQyPYQ6PDfDPCQ1QxJcAqNWzCI3OaIvQwwdPB1TPAg0w9Qp3cIn-HXRjAI2w+vI7Kzd5CVReb-R-V3comI7vFVL3YAng1dT2VI83cbZPZo7IwbWHCg1RKmReanS9fo-bNfUQ9rOPVQ03CVb2MHRoso-bXIwdfAkwtbCY5AWnZPRzCouvYVew1Qz2Pg8IA4Po7QyIw4losxTg9wh7Tw09cw+eUfUow-O4wY5Dcg5Q0Yog+fD41Yr46YuA9fBAxIjrKgkHDXBog-W49YnAuYlXTjNbFJaTffdvQ-WbI42ROwpghYptYEhE3OXE+4rtNorg54qE4HC4h+dIz4yI8kn4oIlQx5a+KDc3YZG4sksEuI+AsQqE+Yx5aeO-MA5PFkrAnI5E2PVE7HEIufaFEfH9DmW6CQKUxNUTAkgZFgrBTxT4tUjU1wqkp4n3PI8rCXR3SbVU9UzUw9P40vNbTQrDEk7Eo0+01fcE2Y2PCDcvVA2040wQjYijeU6-S+MwrnfUnww09UlHCk-Eqou3ZIt4g1T2N0ndXOI0+Mn4wAs0-vUwmTLDFYg-bMpEgwlErHcM1BT2GjCA7DXwsswQtk0YlI17QMnM6UojAUiEoUi06ExUqMt5GMkEtUqoOXGw44hvYdJJHLA00c26cck04rNTGk-spZWoz9W-W0pcwQmY-7OYmcrk8ISrHcicvElFCsuUqsgZO-U3M8sg4Y-4zLReY8lAFInc8PC8xglxT-T9ZvT85cu7PvEA14+kvYwC4M2UvAsM8NJtNA2MqoL8hMoQ61QUw8rozc3jGQxsxc5C1kx0mfY3KmF7GzEc0sxc4-Lsg7JM04y+LLIc5AAzHk3CqoKirUh4tw1c80wdUYxeCvE8+ciiti8sxbGCm8irSFJtKbTMo-Si-ktC3sjC0bBPCVXhci90+S5swi4I+isApw8vHczAjiqc6otbdRHowSmSwTOSqoYyi1PM7igstbRJPU98rE2Ssc+ytHaCowrYtE+PLCp3ayxLWy7ypDfcmPPAv0u-DxBChcuyx8pQp04i72SywReEzSqoXQ6in8nzIZEohKnKkyj3Li1nZy+3RtT9eonc4qi1SKhI-skU8FT2ASyQWpWq0S8-Py2CrTNq+-DSzyxcuq5zFsyS9K+-QLBKrI3KnUrTOsp3QamyscmakqkARy8q0C9E1M8IdSnc1ah0p8lKs4gq-ahSkjA8309DJU+eTQs6qCq88SrPDc3Y3hEsrKgY2a2iwk0UoKg1GrHcz6tajakCzo2fNy+-d6oaymc6kQy66KzCiazkwGrqww4U3q-3TdLDTK6GoGw65Koi1QkfIZKa4S74r6k4n68FN7JtJa0Ksc8m4Gx4pyra5g2E3TUmrKxm+q70+GvyjciaiU7Qhm1Gys56wo2c5Ujy5axc7m0anS9k8FCyrDeK4Sz0pDPKly9m9lB-NWoC9ojw2kmoha-6nc9W+9Xy9GiSq03Y8Ys22G+IyEpqv0t8rROmiHMc825FMa0bV2641izstazW+3ZW6Qwy4WxcwOhy5mzasG+3IotM3WrKqO+Wo6wm+i12uLHclO+bR6nq62+3P8qXNvaGnOprXmqK-mzCu-K4oSzSg4c8lC4O8eMbP6wSqGmWhu-W6knijnTLb2RigGiOruvciuxqzY47CGyVaW+mguRugitO3S4EKmN60dW0ke2vMhS2pqjGwuqSmzEKj29+G3b6lxcCwtde-C6ikGjol4nY-0rcpOoazeB6sS-O8W2fO-ZZS+h29Cq6++8C5G4eq+tan21KvhLDTm5+9ii1Zux5N2Ca5i1W+umB5zG+w29c7fa0mnOu6B0W68j+nPVqiVf22MrJTe1Ci6yu4Umc3YmTde1BqfBWtXV68O3CslQQuB8FDxRBge9e8K5TGO0Gu++3Dbf8lishgR725hmo1hzlR4aQIAA) in the VL editor

[image]

Here's the Python code I'm using:

```py
def make_chart(df, station):
    
    brush = alt.selection(
        type="interval",
        encodings=["x"],
        on="[mousedown[event.altKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
        translate="[mousedown[event.altKey], mouseup] > mousemove!",
        zoom="wheel![event.altKey]",
        )

    interaction = alt.selection(
        type="interval",
        bind="scales",
        on="[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove",
        translate="[mousedown[event.shiftKey], mouseup] > mousemove!",
        zoom="wheel![event.shiftKey]",
        )

    points = alt.Chart().mark_circle().encode(
        alt.X('yearmonthdate(date):T', title='Date'),
        alt.Y('temp:Q', title='Mean Temperature in 2020 (F)'),
        size=alt.Size('wind:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[1, 20], range=[1,500])),
        color=alt.Color('temp:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blueorange', domainMid=32), 
            legend=alt.Legend(title='Mean Temperature')),
        tooltip=['date', 'name', 'temp', 'wind']
    ).properties(
        width=550,
        height=300
    ).transform_filter(
        alt.datum.name == station
    ).add_selection(
        brush
    ).add_selection(interaction)

    bars = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
        x=alt.X('mean(temp)', title='Mean Temperature (F)'),
        y=alt.Y('name:N', title='Station', axis=alt.Axis(labelLimit=90), sort='-x'),
        color=alt.Color('mean(temp):Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blueorange', domainMid=32))
    ).transform_filter(
        brush
    ).properties(
        width=550,
    )

    chart=alt.vconcat(points, bars, data=df, title=f"Mean Temperature Dashboard for NY"
    )

    return chart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart seems to be working fine to me. The only thing I noticed is that some circles are not showing up which can make it look like there is no data there when you brush. If you set your domain to start at zero, these then appear fine and everything works as expected.

[enter link description here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-HU7XSqmAEIgrN-poVvVPJet9Yd9398cjanzOmdBwqtmep5hkhaItwzRrIYBREpg5bcDWIB1jOTYtm2r4dpQjBwDAvb9oOa4npOR6pheaqLsuYqrshG6oduGFYThH6HgRY5Eeec6YNe3C3qUD6YE+L6dph2G4QOPS9IuMAuPeILuHAgIZIYnqiqQmgduimKJAAvDpiQAOQAMIAKIAHLJAASgAggAMokAAKlnmT2en+ry3CrAwzDILc9wkiA2j6IYzS6MWNgQHYFxuJAziuI4SgIAgOQICu-nxHs3DCnClobDBbg7Eo5SVMgEg1PkYD1JiQVtB05zdE8gacnSYZGoKcUJUlKWYgkQSZU0FqBL8HwaraSSpAEjqENkmBen6AbUsGXKTNMxpuEo-JwOWjjLs0njWRKsrIAAnGweS9WiGJYpQLiqCAAC0gqDdahgAMqhnAyYwoG+KaISxISQklBSYq+yggpsWgN+CZJnsTSQ7+mbiXyHlMCgPknXyopKG4GkvJjt0sM0MCHVUMBHM0yhVBIAAcbBKD5BN0FTShXM0dBXGAADspNZr0Q02ml9rjZkk3OtqmHNBAuh0IkQOJCZACaQQACR1H4WNNGIhD+JQyAAPS61MyUdggHyMKQzQdu9uuq9oBuYMlt2mB8mAGywHZXBzHZsB2ABWV3pdsKhKKmhCbaAeME0TJNkxT1O0-TrNMyzbOc9zIOB5RIDumwt1sFTt1XFTyQcMgJccEEOMvfLVkGZKz1GYkgiWSZBkAPIGT2iQAJJmUZ5kmZZyRd63A+UhSyAAGy3B2tzuZByBVDPfmqoY2e5-nhfF2wpfb+X3CV00xlmVZtkOU5Y+WpPVMdhIc8sigi8c8vKVr3nBdF2Xu9sBXF2GAAQpKb03obKtzll3SyABxRyllu6937oPYeA9rIX2BBPN2E877hDdhIZ+mdX4bw-l-HeP9KpNBsn-Zu8tYHJD7gPIeI8bKJEsl3cydlW7mWSCglAE8JAdkOpg1gfDcEvHwQXDmW8d7EP3r-Jo5l26CCMs9Gh5kuGT0OjPARk8hGcHDi-NgRx15iIkZ-EhLxnrV0srXeujdm5tw7tQ2hCCGGqI5o-TRE9tG6LwfonOb8PbGK-qY-+gDgHWVASZcBUCrIOPgfQpBLirg300dPFgwjV4+MMf4z+UjzqkJAOQyhMS6GIMYcw1h7DOG-HHmgjsHNNE4J0RnERGS-HiOyXvXJLwj4WUYWfHsCT3b1PdmkpooirgTwCTkg+IA5EGQUUovuLjF6zxAMycI08n6NJXqMlpG8JntO-tIvJ5ia51wbk3Fu7dO492UcU5xVTL4c14SstZqMOwTxGVnXZBd9lEI6dM7pJ97KOX6Q84ETyOylVed5SFnyxm-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-1F1iSYu6ZjXV75bBDr7bE7WtbvCJvhGvvF8HoiSf7ZUz2+7-bbnLoGX5g13s6fFoZ6T67LxfvubtRj7za3Yweq2-T4nAvvt5PR+z595nM3Mo0Z+xJvPr2GMZ4LwwKHgUjZx-W3hkaDWwaJ76vOZPDsU+N64k7-nYWW93dbvXSrbss-VWzrVmnOsT3UT16DzuPtW8IdDn7rm-ttaW5R+33t8fQfo27+XLxFe+8xytrNxuJ7ro1yHmXYf9sG8i1xjsieDVveT201PqW5npYk-79ROmnda+mzrmvEebvduA979r+Lr5m-CIvQnofXed9R0hkvJ7KeDNiwXvnxOJ+BOc8L1rouldA9XYkof3CF-a7fmwZfUyk0LZTWL5bFns-VLdrvhe0vF9W4RZP6Z5OMv+45Zt87hfXfP5X0h5nXvUrJbfFaec9aFSDZPP-E-SlKPEXMjTfNjfFW-IZWTMfHXaAilNPM-R9C-djK-fFHnTRbjKA4vIbVDeHe3GrCVZPeNF-ZFN-RvHPIPA1QPWgpnT3IA9TC-AZFvVg9g93FzalFrUjAHRA8XHPRHDXE6F3HXOg--GHENQ3Sg8eDmKQ6FN2VJWQw-eQmA7AtFXA8Qy-VXOtAPdXaFM9ZPfdLvKtW3d-e3PjTRXzKwjgnvErbgow3gzbLQ9Aw-aw+gvJafI3VQ7BJtC3Xw-ONgfwhQyPYQ6PDfDPCQ1QxJcAqNWzCI3OaIvQwwdPB1TPAg0w9Qp3cIn-HXRjAI2w+vI7Kzd5CVReb-R-V3comI7vFVL3YAng1dT2VI83cbZPZo7IwbWHCg1RKmReanS9fo-bNfUQ9rOPVQ03CVb2MHRoso-bXIwdfAkwtbCY5AWnZPRzCouvYVew1Qz2Pg8IK4Po7QyIw4losxTg9wh7Tw09cw+eUfUow-O4wY5Dcg5Q0Yog+fD41Yr46YuA9fBAxIjrKgkHDXBog-W49YnAuYlXTjNbFJaTffdvQ-WbI42ROwpghYptYEhE3OXE+4rtNorg54qE4HC4h+dIz4yI8kn4oIlQx5a+KDc3YZG4sksEuI+AsQqE+Yx5aeO-MA5PFkrAnI5E2PVE7HEIufaFEfH9DmW6CQKUxNUTAkgZFgrBTxT4tUjU1wqkp4n3PI8rCXR3SbVU9UzUw9P40vNbTQrDEk7Eo0+01fcE2Y2PCDcvVA2040wQjYijeU6-S+MwrnfUnww09UlHCk-Eqou3ZIt4g1T2N0ndXOI0+Mn4wAs0-vUwmTLDFYg-bMpEgwlErHcM1BT2GjCA7DXwsswQtk0YlI17QMnM6UojAUiEoUi06ExUqMt5GMkEtUqoOXGw44hvYdJJHLA00c26cck04rNTGk-spZWoz9W-W0pcwQmY-7OYmcrk8ISrHcicvElFCsuUqsgZO-U3M8sg4Y-4zLReY8lAFInc8PC8xglxT-T9ZvT85cu7PvEA14+kvYwC4M2UvAsM8NJtNA2MqoL8hMoQ61QUw8rozc3jGQxsxc5C1kx0mfY3KmF7GzEc0sxc4-Lsg7JM04y+LLIc5AAzHk3CqoKirUh4tw1c80wdUYxeCvE8+ciiti8sxbGCm8irSFJtKbTMo-Si-ktC3sjC0bBPCVXhci90+S5swi4I+isApw8vHczAjiqc6otbdRHowSmSwTOSqoYyi1PM7igstbRJPU98rE2Ssc+ytHaCowrYtE+PLCp3ayxLWy7ypDfcmPPAv0u-DxBChcuyx8pQp04i72SywReEzSqoXQ6in8nzIZEohKnKkyj3Li1nZy+3RtT9eonc4qi1SKhI-skU8FT2ASyQWpWq0S8-Py2CrTNq+-DSzyxcuq5zFsyS9K+-QLBKrI3KnUrTOsp3QamyscmakqkARy8q0C9E1M8IdSnc1ah0p8lKs4gq-ahSkjA8309DJU+eTQs6qCq88SrPDc3Y3hEsrKgY2a2iwk0UoKg1GrHcz6tajakCzo2fNy+-d6oaymc6kQy66KzCiazkwGrqww4U3q-3TdLDTK6GoGw65Koi1QkfIZKa4S74r6k4n68FN7JtJa0Ksc8m4Gx4pyra5g2E3TUmrKxm+q70+GvyjciaiU7Qhm1Gys56wo2c5Ujy5axc7m0anS9k8FCyrDeK4Sz0pDPKly9m9lB-NWoC9ojw2kmoha-6nc9W+9Xy9GiSq03Y8Ys22G+IyEpqv0t8rROmiHMc825FMa0bV2641izstazW+3ZW6Qwy4WxcwOhy5mzasG+3IotM3WrKqO+Wo6wm+i12uLHclO+bR6nq62+3P8qXNvaGnOprXmqK-mzCu-K4oSzSq4c8lC4O8eMbP6wSqGmWhu-W6knijnTLb2RigGiOruvciuxqzY47CGyVaW+mguRugitO3S4EKmN60dW0ke2vMhS2pqjGwuqSmzEKj29+G3b6lxcCwtde-C6ikGjol4nY-0rcpOoazeB6sS-O8W2fO-ZZS+h29Cq6++8C5G4eq+tan21KvhLDTm5+9ii1Zux5N2Ca5i1W+umB5zG+w29c7fa0mnOu6B0W68j+nPVqiVf22MrJTe1Ci6yu4Umc3YmTde1BqfBWtXV68O3CslQQuB8FDxRBge9e8K5TGO0Gu++3Dbf8lishgR725hmo1hzlR4aQIAA)

Comment: Thanks David! Turned out to be nans in the "wind" column. They obviously don't show up with a size encoding. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I've been waiting for this! Won't be long before you get your 1000 :D. What will you do then?